# Yii2 form fields in dropdown appended to another field

Tags: forms, yii2, glyphicons

I'm building a form where I should insert "Total year billed" or "month by month billed" in dropdown.
This is the code with prepended glyphicon icon:

```
<?= $form->field($model, "total_year_billed" , ['template' => '
                       <div class="input-group ">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span>
                      </span>
                      {input}
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                      <div class="dropdown">
                      <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >trim</a>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li>JAN</li>
                       <li>FEB</li>
                       <li>MAR</li>
                       </ul>
                       </div> 
                      </span>
                      </div>
                      {error}{hint}'])->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
```

I'm trying to insert input fields instead of JAN FEB MAR but it won't works:

```
<?= $form->field($model, "jan")->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?>
```

The fields jan, feb ecc. are on the same table of "total_year_billed" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem splitting first input field and adding a separate dropdown button.
I would prefer just one field with all options but so everything is working.

Now the code figure so:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <?= $form->field($model, "total_year_billed" , ['template' => '
  <div class="input-group ">
  <div class="input-group ">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span>
  </span>
  {input}                      
  </div>
  {error}{hint}'])->textInput(['maxlength' => true])->label(false) ?> 
</div>
    <!-- begin of dropdown fields-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class = "btn-group">
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default">Monthly-billed</button>
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
          <span class = "caret"></span>
          <span class = "sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>
          <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
            <li>
              <?= $form->field($model, "jan" , ['template' => '
              <div class="input-group ">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
              Jan 
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span>
              </span>
              {input}                      
              </div>
              {error}{hint}'])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'value' => 0])->label(false) ?>
             </li>
            <li>
              <?= $form->field($model, "feb" , ['template' => '
              <div class="input-group ">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
              Feb 
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span>
              </span>
              {input}                      
              </div>
              {error}{hint}'])->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'value' => 0])->label(false) ?>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот аккуратное решение в PHP стиле:

```
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;

...

echo $form->field($model, 'cost', [
    'addon' => [
        'prepend' => [
            'asButton' => true,
            'content' => Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'cost_condition', DeliveryTypeHelper::getList(), [
                    'class' => 'input-group-selected btn btn-default dropdown-toggle',
                ]),
        ],
    ],
]);
```